# Whats the MPPZ 3610 on Arduino nano every

Tags: arduino-nano-every

I'm curious what's the MPPZ chip on my Arduino nano everu

Comment: You mean MPM3610? https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mpm3610.html

Comment: Do you have a photo of your MPPZ 3610? Or have you mis-read the code? Please [edit] your question and upload a (cropped) photo.

Comment: I just didn't understand it at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Arduino Nano Every [datasheet](https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/datasheets/ABX00028-datasheet.pdf):

> MPM3610 (DC-DC)
>
> - Regulates input voltage from up to 21V with a minimum of 65% efficiency @minimum load
> - More than 85% efficiency @12V